# Stopping a svg animation

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I would like to stop a svg via Jquery. The svg image is placed directly into the DOM via viewHelper (like Typo3Fluid).
If I add a class `.stop` with `animation-play-state: paused;` It doesn't pause the svg.

JS:

```
    var bulletlist = function (container) {
    var self = this;
    this.container = container;

    $(".x-control", self.container).click(function() {
        //remove & show button
        $(".x-control").toggleClass("x-play");

        //start and stop svg
        $(".wv_bulletlist svg").toggleClass("stop");
        //$(".wv_bulletlist svg").css("animation-play-state", "paused");

        return false;
    });
};

$(function () {
    $('.wv_bulletlist').each(function () {
        new bulletlist(this);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
<style>path {
  stroke-dasharray: 125;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 4s .01s linear forwards infinite;
}
#t-horizontal, #t-vertical {
  stroke-dasharray: 30;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation-name: dash-short;
}
#t, #t-horizontal, #t-vertical {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}
#s {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes dash-short {
  from, 30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 30;
  }
  76%, to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 125;
  }
  67%, to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}</style>
```

All of this has to be compatible with IE 11 and I can't know what svg will be placed there beforehand.
Would appreciate any tips or suggestions.

Kind regards

Comment: Without knowing what animation is **on (or in)** the SVG, this is gonna be hard...especially if it's hardcoded or in SMIL.  A "non-working" example would be helpful here....but since these animations are *part* of the svg their internal CSS would apply after any class - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG_animation#SVG_animation_using_CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is attached to one or more `<path>` element(s), your `stop` class is set on an element with the selector `".wv_bulletlist svg"`. CSS animation properties are not inheritable. You must set the `animation-play-state: paused` on the same path element(s) that have the running animation.

Comment: this along with SetTimeout() is wonderful